# How to give a heavy page to bots?

Tags: web, captcha, bots

Nowadays there is a lot of applications to change IP causing a nightmare to block a bot because the attack can come from many places. I want to give a bot a heavy page to make them an excessive load and desist to continue hacking my website. Maybe a page with a heavy JS on it. I put a Captcha and they can't get nothing from my website but the queries to my website continue. Any idea on how to do that? Any idea on how to fight this new technique of changing IPs?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to block them at the firewall level.
If as you said, they are not solving the captcha, it means that these bots are not really interested on getting data from your website.
But they are only generating bad traffic.

Blocking them before they reach the webserver can be really helpful, there are a huge amount of black-list on internet.
Some of them are updated very frequently, you just need a script that gets them and add these IP to your firewall (iptables?)

Comment: The problem here is that the attacker is changing the IP all the time. What IP you will block in firewall if it is changing all the time? I was thinking in Sessions but this consume my resources. The other option is do something with cookies to identify the attacker.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider writing a Fail2ban rule based on your webserver logs.
This can be helpful if this attacker runs always the HTTP requests in the same format, maybe a faked User-Agent?